# If I were to shake a black hole, does it grow bigger?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, black-holes, gravitational-waves

Imagine I were to shake a black hole rigorously, does it grow bigger? I think it will simply radiate all the kinetic energy gained from the shaking as gravitational wave right? In the normal case, if I shake a planet, its mass remains unchanged but gains kinetic energy then in the case of a black hole, its mass should remain intact but the missing energy must go somewhere. I bet it is lost as gravitational wave but need someone to confirm.

Comment: By shaking a black hole do you mean just giving it (kinetic?) energy, or something else too?

Comment: How are you going to shake a black hole? There are several possible ways and the answer depends on the details.

Comment: the LIGO observation showed one black hole shaking another, before merging, and yes there are gravitational waves that were detected.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO